# Error establishing a database connection from a SQL containerized database with localhost

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a container running a DBMS (a database) with a mysql:5.7 and to access the database with a container running a CMS (workpress in my case).

I have a docker-compose.yml that generates and run the containers on a backend network :

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: sql
    networks:
      - backend

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    container_name: wordpress-container
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: sql
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - backend
  
networks:
  backend:
```

When I run my containers and try an access from localhost, I guess the error "Error establishing a database connection".

I have first tried to see if the password "sql" wasn't set for the containers, but it wasn't the case as I was able to log in the database in the mySQL container with that password.

Next, I tried updating the wp-config.php file in the wordpress container with informations from the docker-compose.yml to no avail again.

The backend network is also running without issues.

I can't find the source of the problem after trying this. Can you help me please ?